# How to Project an Image to a Sphere

Tags: java, mercator

I am trying to get the following image to be projected to a sphere using mercator:
[image]

I have gotten this far using the formula from this : [how map 2d grid points (x,y) onto sphere as 3d points (x,y,z)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732590/how-map-2d-grid-points-x-y-onto-sphere-as-3d-points-x-y-z)

My code is the following to generate the coordinates from (X,Y):

```
public void generateSphericalCoords(){
    int R = 400; // Image Radius
    int S = 400; // Sphere Radius

    float longitude = (float)(this.x)/R;
    float latitude = (float) (2*Math.atan(Math.exp((double)(this.y)/R)) - Math.PI/2);
    sphericalX = (int) (S*Math.cos(latitude) * Math.cos(longitude)) + 300;
    sphericalY = (int) (S*Math.cos(latitude) * Math.sin(longitude)) + 300;
    sphericalZ = (int) (S*Math.sin(longitude));
    //System.out.println(sphericalX + " " + sphericalY + " " + sphericalZ);
}
```

However, instead of getting a perfect sphere, I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have gotten to the following formula:

```
    float longitude = (float) ((float)(Math.PI*this.x)/R - Math.PI/2);
    float latitude = (float) (Math.PI*2*Math.atan(Math.exp((float)(this.y)/R)));
    sphericalX = (int) (S*Math.cos(latitude) * Math.cos(longitude)) + 300;
    sphericalY = (int) (S*Math.cos(latitude) * Math.sin(longitude)) + 300;
    sphericalZ = (int) (S*Math.sin(longitude));
```

However, I have gotten an odd ring along the outside edge, as shown:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't longitude go from 0 to 2π and latitude from -π/2 to π/2? You're scaling both longitude and latitude between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I am. How would I change my formulas accordingly? I haven't messed around with any cartography or projection.

Comment: I haven't either, I'm just thinking about how longitudes and latitudes work on Earth.

Comment: Yep. I think that did the trick. Sadly, the image isn't necessarily tileable, so it doesn't mesh well. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, in the Mercator projection the top and bottom edges both represent a single point, and thus should be the same colour. And the left and right edges should be joinable.

Comment: It looks like you were right, I changed the formula and it started to mesh better. I updated the problem, and you can see where I am at now.