# Math: Mercator Projection Convert 360 video pixel coordinate to sphere surface coordinate

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I was trying to map the 360 video pixel coordinate to sphere surface coordinate but I couldn't get right result... It just mapped to the wrong position I already know the points of the XY data for 360 video pixels.

[how map 2d grid points (x,y) onto sphere as 3d points (x,y,z)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732590/how-map-2d-grid-points-x-y-onto-sphere-as-3d-points-x-y-z)

I checked this link and I copied method from this but what I'm getting is not mapped to the desired position.

### How can I get radius from the pixels?

I am not sure if I'm passing right radius for imageRadius but I thought it will be circumference/PI to get radius and the video ratio is 4096x2048. I also tried to pass the number 1 because UV is 0-1 but it was not right...

### Is Method wrong?

Maybe the method is wrong. I passed random numbers into the imageRadius but couldn't get the right position... If I make X to negative number the seems like little bit closer to result....?

### Current Result

https://youtu.be/t0I7Hlb-tbk
It mapped to up right position with the method that I found online...

### Project File

https://drive.google.com/a/swordfish-sf.com/file/d/0B45RYzVs0t0_VVdaaHdmNHRWTk0/view?usp=sharing
If somebody can check the Unity project file that will be great...

### Current Code

```
public class mapScript : MonoBehaviour {

public int input = 4098;
float imageRadius = 4098f / Mathf.PI; //2098? 3072? 4098?
float radius;
public GameObject testSphere;

void Start () {
    radius = this.transform.localScale.x;
}


void Update () {
    imageRadius = input / Mathf.PI;
    int currentFrame = (int)this.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().frame;

    testSphere.transform.position = MercatorProjection(mapVals[currentFrame,0],mapVals[currentFrame,1]);
}

Vector3 MercatorProjection(float xVal, float yVal)
{
    float lon = (xVal / imageRadius);
    float lat = (2 * Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(yVal / imageRadius)) - Mathf.PI / 2);


    float calcX = radius * Mathf.Cos(lat) * Mathf.Cos(lon);
    float calcY = radius * Mathf.Cos(lat) * Mathf.Sin(lon);
    float calcZ = radius * Mathf.Sin(lat);

    Vector3 result = new Vector3(calcX,calcY,calcZ);
    Debug.Log(result);
    return result;
}



float[,] mapVals = new float[,] {
{1969.21f, 928.625f},
{1969.6f, 928.533f},
{1968.92f, 928.825f},
{1968.68f, 929f},
{1968.47f, 929.067f},
{1968.41f, 929.025f},
{1968.48f, 928.992f},
....
};
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, the radius is arbitrary. The pixel coordinates only map to the directional coordinates (polar [`θ`] and azimuthal [`ϕ`] angles).

---

We can do this by mapping each pixel to equal `θ` and `ϕ` intervals. The diagram below illustrates a low-resolution setup:

[image]

Let us adopt the convention that, for an image of with `W`, `ϕ = 0` corresponds to:

- Even `W`: half way between `X = floor((W - 1) / 2)` and `X = ceil((W - 1) / 2)`
- Odd `W`: in the middle of the pixel column at `X = floor((W - 1) / 2)`

The pixel row at `Y` maps to the equilatitudinal line at `θ = (Y + 0.5) / H * π`.

To map all pixels in their *entirety*, let `X` start at `-0.5` instead of `0`, and end at `W - 0.5`; likewise for `Y`. Since integer coordinates map to the *centers* of the pixel regions shown above, this allows the whole area of any particular pixel to be addressed. You may need this later on if you plan on doing multi-sampling filtering for e.g. anti-aliasing.

Code:

```
Vector3 Mercator(float x, float y, int w, int h)
{
   // outside of valid pixel region
   if (x < -0.5f || x >= w - 0.5f || y < -0.5f || y >= h - 0.5f)
      return new Vector3();

   float theta = (y + 0.5f) / h * Math.PI;
   float phi = ((x + 0.5f) / w - 0.5f) * 2.0 * Math.PI;

   float c_t = Math.Cos(theta);
   return new Vector3(c_t * Math.Cos(phi), c_t * Math.Sin(phi), Math.Sin(theta));
}
```

... and multiply the resulting direction vector by any "radius" you like, since it has (basically) nothing to do with the mapping anyway.