# Determine 3D Longitude and Latitude based on radius, x and y 3D globe THREE.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, three.js

Currently I am trying to understand a Codpen where this guy has JSON data being fed into a Javascript app that plots coordinates using x and y.

Instead of using longitude and latitude to plot for example Hong Kong, he uses these coordinates.

```
{"x": 768,"y": 342,"name": "", "country":"Hong Kong"}
```

I want to be able to put in x and y a longitude and latitude value, but I can not figure out how to multiply or divide, a simple solution to go with his code. I am new to Javascript, but am trying to understand how to plot coordinates more efficiently on this specific project.

Is there a simple equation I could use to be able to plot more easily on this pen.
Thanks.

https://codepen.io/Flamov/pen/MozgXb

Comment: It's funny you should ask that. [This example](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-optimize-lots-of-objects.html) uses similar data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is basically using the [Mercator Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) to convert `radius, lat, long` into euclidean `x, y, z` coordinates, as mentioned on lines 860+ of the JSFiddle you provided, and is using [this S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734509) as reference. Since radius is constant throughout the globe, you don't need to repeat that value for each point, it's just hard-coded into the example.

Mercator is a bit confusing because the scale stretches towards infinity as you approach the poles. As an easier alternative, you could use `Vector3.setFromSphericalCoords(rad, lat, long)` [as outlined in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.setFromSphericalCoords) and it sets `x, y, z` for you. The main difference is that this approach doesn't cause distortion near the poles. It takes `lat, long` in radians:

- `lat` ranges from `[0, Pi]` (north pole to south pole)
- `long` ranges from `[0, 2*Pi]` (around the equator)