# Unity - Mapping input on a 2D Plane to a 3D Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapping

So I've got an idea and I'm wondering if it's even possible, and if so, how to implement it. Say I have a 3D Globe in a scene as a representation of Earth, and in the corner of the same scene I have a 2D map of Earth. I want to click on an area on the 2D Map, say Japan, and have a gameobject appear both on the 2D map and at the correct spherical coordinates for Japan on the 3D globe. Vice versa implementation would be great too. Is that something that can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project 2D points to 3D sphere, single object for every country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153411/project-2d-points-to-3d-sphere-single-object-for-every-country)

Comment: or more generically: [how map 2d grid points (x,y) onto sphere as 3d points (x,y,z)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732590/how-map-2d-grid-points-x-y-onto-sphere-as-3d-points-x-y-z)